# Create nested array having an element path array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, nested

I have this array:

```
var array ={data: [
        { id:'1',
          name:'first',
          data:[]
 }]}
```

and i have this path: `path = ['3','1','2'];`
How can i push data based on the path dynamically and create this:

```
  array.data= myData;
  array.data[3].data= myData;
  array.data[3].data[1].data =myData;
  array.data[3].data[1].data[2].data= myData;
```

myData stores data from a server and changes everytime

myData example

```
var myData = 
{ id:'5',
          name:'abc',
          data:[]
 },
{ id:'7',
          name:'def',
          data:[]
 }
```

The wanted result should be like this:
I want to be able to create this array like that and the data to be accessible like above.

```
var array ={data: [
        { id:'1',
          name:'first',
          data:[]
 },{ id:'2',
          name:'first',
          data:[]
 },
{ id:'3',
          name:'first',
          data:[]
 },
{ id:'4',
          name:'first',
          data:[
                { id:'5',
                  name:'first',
                  data:[]
                },
                { id:'6',
                 name:'first',
                 data:[
                        { id:'7',
                          name:'first',
                          data:[]
                         },
                       { id:'8',
                         name:'first',
                         data:[
                                { id:'8',
                                  name:'first',
                                 data:[]
                                },
                                { id:'8',
                         name:'first',
                         data:[]
                     }]
                     }]
                }]
 }]}
```

Comment: what is `myData`

Comment: I edited the question. its basically same array object which i want to push

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. for example, why is the first `data` an object, instead of an array as all following `data` properties?

Comment: please add the pathes as well.

Comment: the path is written above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the path by preserving the last index and take the result object as start value.

Inside of `reduce` assign an array to `data`, if it does not exists and assign a new object to the `data` property with the actual value pf the path array as index.

```js
var result = {},
    data = { id: '1', name: 'first' },
    path = [3, 1, 2],
    last = path.pop(),
    final = path.reduce((o, i) => {
        o.data = o.data || [];
        return o.data[i] = o.data[i] || {};
    }, result);

final[last] = Object.assign({}, data, final[last] && { data: final[last].data });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I want it to be nested. the 3 , 1 ,2 stands for  object 4 which will have 2 nested objects and and the second nested object will have another 3 nested objects. it will be like a tree

Comment: I updated the wanted result. The data is the same just with different names and ids

Comment: i have no idea. you have a path with three elements and two object. what should happen with it?

Comment: I want to push Mydata first on array[3].data then on array[3].data[1] and then on array[3].data[1].data[2]. Mydata changes on every click i make and stores diferrent data. I achieved this the static way with for loops but the problem is if you have  a path with 6 elements you will make 6 loops? i need something dynamical. Based on the path above i want my final array to be the one above

Comment: on every click  myData changes with the desired data inside. i just made a sample. take as example the data in the final result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199614/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-mendi).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to dynamically construct an object (ie `result` as shown below) that is, nested clones of the `myData` object  from a supplied `path` array.

One approach to this, that would produce the required access method (ie `array.data[3].data[1].data[2].data`) would be via the `reduceRight()` method on the `path` array as shown:

```js
const myData = { id: '1', name: 'first' };
const path = ['3', '1', '2'];

const array = { 
  data : path.reduceRight((acc, part) => 
    ({ [part] : { data : { ...acc, ...myData } }}), {}) 
}

console.log(array.data[3].data);
console.log(array.data[3].data[1].data);
console.log(array.data[3].data[1].data[2].data);
```